# Build XPATH expression to get and click button element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I'm building a scraper with selenium, and I got it up and running except for one data field I'm missing. I need to first push a button, then get the value. But I haven't been able to push the button, because I can't seem to build the correct xpath expression to get it with selenium,

The url is this one: https://www.ikea.com/mx/es/p/kallax-estante-blanco-80275887/

And I need to click the button "Medidas" (scroll halfway through the page, right between "Detalles del producto" and "Productos similares") to open a side panel and get the info I need.
But so far, I haven't been able to set the correct XPATH expression for the button.

I tried with

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(
     "//button[@class='range-revamp-chunky-header']"
 ).click()
```

But this way it clicked the first button ("Detalles del producto")

Also tried with something like

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(
     "//button[@class='range-revamp-chunky-header' AND @text='Medidas']"
 ).click()
```

But I haven't been able to make it work, I just got this error:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@class='range-revamp-chunky-header' and @text='Medidas']"}
```

By the way, the list of buttons is dynamic... sometimes, there can be 1, 2, 3 or 4 buttons with the same class, only difference I can see is the text of the button, so getting always the 2nd button with that class (like in the URL provided) won't always work.

Comment: Perhaps you should try this one: //span[contains(text(),'Medidas')]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To click on the element with text as ***Medidas*** you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Medidas']").click()
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193625/how-to-click-on-a-element-through-selenium-python/54194511#54194511) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):

- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(., 'login or register')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: If you did want to target the button, you could use `//button[@class="range-revamp-chunky-header" and @type="button" and contains(., "Medidas")]`